# Не действует разделения

Tags: javascript

Такой Вопрос.
Почему я не могу к slides написать style.block?

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
function plusSlides(n){
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n){
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n){
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dot = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

    if(n > slides.length){
        slideIndex = 1;
    }
    if(n < 1){
        slideIndex = slides.length;
    }
    for(i=0; i <slides.length; i++){
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for(i = 0; i < dot.length; i++){
        dot[i].className = dot[i].className.replace("active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = 'block';
    dot[slideIndex-1].className += "active";
}
```

Comment: Вопрос непонятен, объясните всё подробнее и вообще что этот кусок кода делает

Comment: что значит не могу?

Comment: Детально. Когда я пишу slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = 'block'; в браузере ошибка.

Comment: этот кусок кода за слайдер

Comment: Легче всего оперировать добавлением класса на данный элемент чем делать это через js. Т.е. то, что делалось с `dot`, сделать и с `slides` - повесить на объект новый класс что-то вроде `slideShow/slideHide`, который будет описан в css с правилом `display:block; / display:none`. Ну а причина почему не работает. может быт в том, что 1) объект slides может быть пуст (length = 0) 2) slideIndex может выходить за пределы массива.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вы имеете в виду задать стиль для определенного блока. Дело в том, что в slides записан массив данных т.к. он ссылается сразу на все элементы с классом mySlides (getElement**s**ByClassName). Думаю следующее решение вам подойдет:

```
...
slides[slideIndex-1].style.setAttribute("style", "display:block;");
dot[slideIndex-1]...
```

Comment: не работает все равно

Comment: html код приложите, который относится непосредственно к этому скрипту

Comment: благодарю, уже решил проблему.